# Custom CSS does not work correctly in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, hover

I have a custom section created for my WP page. You may find CSS and HTML here: http://www.cssdesk.com/J469A

When you hover over the image, you will see that it will be replaced by the semi-transparent background in my code.

However, when I insert the code to my WordPress website, it does not work this way. On hover the transparent backgorund covers only the area taken by the text but not the entire picture as it is supposed to be.

You may have a look here: http://www.sflsupport.org/programs/ It's the very last section (Webinar Archive)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with `display:table` , it should be `display:block`

Give a try with the following updated CSS

```
span.text-content {
  background: rgba(26,33,43,0.9);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* display: table; updated to display:block below */
  display:block;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed this but unfortunately, it does not work.

Comment: I checked your site and it seems to be working fine. please double check your site

Comment: FF and Chrome both working perfectly, let me know which browser are you checking

Comment: Thanks so much for checking. However, when you shrink the size of the browser, you will see that the content does not stay inside the box. (I used Chrome and Mozilla). @sanjeevk

Comment: you'll have to make the font size responsive, using media query you can decrease the font size, or use font size in vw, check this link for responsive font size: https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Answer (score 0):

Please replace

```
span.text-content{
 display: table;
 ...
}
```

with

```
span.text-content{
 display: block;
 ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed this but unfortunately, it does not work.

Comment: No, you may check the page http://www.sflsupport.org/programs/ . If you shrink the size of your browser, you will see that the content of the section does not stay inside the box. And it should be inside. @sasikumar

Comment: add     overflow-y: auto;